# I want to make all videos can play/pause JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with some videos. I want to implement the ability to click on a button to make a video play and if I click another button the current video will stop and the next video will start playing.

How can something like this be achieved?

My project is similar to Netflix's main page.

My Website:
https://capcom2store.com/mov4k.php

This is my JS:

```html
<script>
    var videoElement = document.getElementById("myVideo");

    function playPause() {
        if (videoElement.paused) {
            videoElement.play();
        } else {
            videoElement.pause();
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: FYI, only add tags that are relevant to the question at hand. I removed the PHP and jQuery tags here since there's nothing in the question about either.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you can do is to do something similar to the following:

```js
// Get all video elements on the current page
const videoElements = document.querySelectorAll("video"); 

for (const videoEl of videoElements) {
  // Listen to clicks on every one of the videos
  videoEl.onclick = () => {
    if (videoEl.paused) {
      for (const video of videoElements) {
        // When starting to play one video, pause all others
        video.pause();
      }
      videoEl.play();
    } else {
      videoEl.pause()
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
<video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
```

Although this is a very simple example, because it takes over all of the click events of the video elements. It would be better to detect clicks another way (like having an overlay element or a button)

Comment: @M. Eriksson   i need other way like when i click the image show video and the video will play, can you Help me with that please?